# Difference between instantiation and specialization in c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

What is the difference between specialization and instantiation in context of C++ templates. From what I have read so far the following is what I have understood about specialization and instantiation.

```
template <typename T>
struct Struct
{

     T x;
};

template<>
struct Struct <int> //specialization
{

    //code
};

int main()
{
   Struct <int> s; //specialized version comes into play
   Struct <float> r; // Struct <float> is instantiated by the compiler as shown below

}
```

Instantiation of `Struct <float>` by the compiler

```
template <typename T=float>
struct Struct
{
    float x;
}
```

Is my understanding of template instantiation and specialization correct?

Answer (score 60):

### (Implicit) Instantiation

This is what you refer to as instantiation (as mentioned in the Question)

### Explicit Instantiation

This is when you tell the compiler to instantiate the template with given types, like this:

```
template Struct<char>; // used to control the PLACE where the template is inst-ed
```

### (Explicit) Specialization

This is what you refer to as specialization (as mentioned in the Question)

### Partial Specialization

This is when you give an alternative definition to a template for a subset of types, like this:

```
template<class T> class Struct<T*> {...} // partial specialization for pointers
```

Comment: And in the C++ standard (but nowhere else) there's also implicit specialization, which is what the compiler does when you instantiate a template and no explicit specialization is selected.

Comment: @Redl Citations concerning what you said are highly recommended, if you have some.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful; I'd also like to mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/2351155/1043529 -- there are caveats regarding shared libraries because, as I understand it, an 'unused' instantiation in one is stripped while another referencing the instantiation trusts that it will be resolved at some point during linkage. The result is a fairly misleading 'undefined reference' unless you do your instantiations in headers. I took that error to mean that I had to provide every explicit specialization!

Answer (score 25):

> What is the difference between specialization and instantiation in context of C++ templates?

Normally (no specializations present) the compiler will create ***instantiations*** of a template when they are used, by substituting actual template parameters (`int` in your example) for the formal template parameters (`T`) and then compile the resulting code.

If a ***specialization*** is present, then for the (set of) special template parameter(s) specified by that specialization, that specialization's implementation is to be used instead of what the compiler would create.

Answer (score 14):

Overview

- Specialization: The class, function or class member you get when substituting template arguments into the template parameters of a class template or function template.
- Instantiation: The act of creating a specialization out of a template or class template member. The specialization can be created out of a partial specialization, class template member or out of a primary class or function template.

An explicit specialization is one that defines the class, function or member *explicitly*, without an instantiation.

Comment: Would that be [class template] member, or class [template member]?

Comment: Also - perhaps - beneath the full answer as given, you could append two additional bullet points with examples.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum a "class [template member]" is also a "partial specialization ... or primary class or function template", so is covered by those. I meant it to be a "[class template] member". These are not templates, therefore my phrasing "template or class template member".

Comment: The mentioning of it in the first bullet should have said "class member", not "class template member" (which is what the Standard uses when defining "specialization").

Answer (score 13):

A template specialization actually changes the behaviour of the template for a specific type. eg convert to a string:

```
template<typename T> std::string convertToString( const T& t )
{
   std::ostringstream oss;
   oss << t;
   return oss.str();
}
```

Let's specialise that though when our type is already a std::string as it is pointless going through ostringstream

```
template<> std::string convertToString( const std::string & t )
{
   return t;
}
```

You can specialise for classes too.

Now instantiation: this is done to allow you to move the compilation for certain types into one compilation unit. This can save you both compilation time and sometimes code-bloat too. 
Let's say we make the above into a class called StringConvert rather than a function.

```
template<typename T>
class StringConvert
{
 public:
  // 4 static functions to convert from T to string, string to T,
   // T to wstring and wstring to T using streams
 };
```

We will convert a lot of integers to strings so we can instantiate it: Put this inside one header

```
 extern template class StringConvert<int>;
```

Put this inside one compilation unit:

```
 template class StringConvert<int>;
```

Note that the above can also be done (without the extern in the header) with functions that are actually not implemented inline. One of your compilation units will implement them. However then your template is limited only to instantiated types. Sometimes done when the template has a virtual destructor.

Comment: Note that my example for specialization isn't really a great one because it's a function so you can just overload it. However if you need to do this inside a class template, it would be done that way, e.g. you have some traits class for types and one of them is converting to a string. It's just easier for demonstration purposes to show why you specialize for a type through that function.

Answer (score 10):

In c++ 11.

**instantiation:**

Instantiate the template with given template arguments

```
template <typename T>
struct test{ T m; };

template test<int>;//explicit instantiation
```

*which result in a definition of a struct with a identifier `test<int>`*

```
test<int> a;//implicit instantiation
```

if `template <typename T> struct test` has been instantiated with argument `T = int` before(explicit or implicit), then it's just a struct instantiation. Otherwise it will instantiate `template <typename T> struct test` with argument `T = int` first implicitly and then instantiate an instance of struct `test<int>`

**specialization:**

a specialization is **still a template**, you still need instantiation to get the real code.

```
template <typename T>
struct test{ T m; };
template <> struct test<int>{ int newM; } //specialization
```

The most useful of template specialization is probably that you can create different templates for different template arguments which means **you can have different definitions of class or function for different template arguments**.

```
template<> struct test<char>{ int cm; }//specialization for char
test<char> a;
a.cm = 1;

template<> struct test<long> { int lm; }//specialization for long
test<long> a;
a.lm = 1;
```

In addition to these **full template specialization**s above, there(only class template) exits **partial template specialization** also.

```
template<typename T>
struct test {};
template <typename T> struct test<const T>{};//partial specialization for const T


template <typename A, typename B>
struct test {};
template <typename B> struct test<int, B>{};//partial specialization for A = int
```

Comment: It is an error here: `template test<int>;` You must add the keyword `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

A specialized template is no longer just a template. Instead, it is either an actual class or an actual function.

A specialization is from either an instantiation or an explicit specialization, cf 14.7.4 below.

An instantiation is based on a primary template definition. A sample implicit class template instantiation,

```
template<typename T>
class foo {}

foo<int> foo_int_object;
```

A sample explicit class template instantiation,

```
template class foo<double>;
```

An explicit specialization has a different definition from it's primary template.

```
template<>
class foo<bool> {}
```

// extract from standard

14 Templates

14.7 Template instantiation and specialization

4 An instantiated template specialization can be either implicitly instantiated (14.7.1) for a given argument
list or be explicitly instantiated (14.7.2). A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either
instantiated or explicitly specialized (14.7.3).