# C++ template full specialization syntax

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, template-specialization

When you declare a template specialization, what's the difference between the syntax with (1) and without angular brackets (2).

Why the version 1 fails if an implementation (definition) of the method is not provided (like in this case) with the error: `undefined reference to int f<int>(int)` while the version 2 works as expected?

```
template <typename T> T f(T val) {
    return val;
}
template<> int f<int>(int val); // 1
template int f<int>(int val);   // 2
int main() {
    cout << f(555);
}
```

---

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323597/1417883) but it does not explicitly descrive the difference between these different syntax.

Comment: #1 is specialization, #2 is explicit instantiation.

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323597/1417883) you linked explains these forms as being specialization and instantiation. Furthermore, it also links to another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates) that explains their difference.

Comment: You're right. The comment "same as above" was confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just confused **explicit instantiation** and **template specialization**.

No1 is *template spcialization*, means you want to define a special version for the template with the given type, so you have to provide a potentially different defination for it.

No2 is *explicit instantiation*, means you want the compiler to instantiate the template with the given type explicitly. It will be generated based on the primary template.

[Explicit instantiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

> An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the
>   function or member function they refer to. It may appear in the
>   program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given
>   argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the program.
>
> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents
>   implicit instantiations: the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided somewhere else in the program.

[explicit (full) template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

> Allows customizing the template code for a given set of template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're telling the compiler to specialize the template function (saying "the template for type int is different"), but you're not providing the specialized function **definition**, hence the "undefined reference". This error pretty much always means: "You declared a function, used it elsewhere, and did not define it".