# Template definition with "struct structname<..>" is correct?

Tags: c++

This code is from C++ STL v3.3 concept_checks.h, 293-300:

```
template <class _Func, class _Arg>
struct _STL_UNARY_FUNCTION_ERROR<_Func, void, _Arg> {
  static void
  __unary_function_requirement_violation(_Func& __f,
                                      const _Arg& __arg) {
    __f(__arg);
  }
};
```

Does C++ allow a template to be defined like "struct structname<..>"?

In the above example, what is the use of "<_Func, void, _Arg>"?

If we delete "<_Func, void, _Arg>", does it affect anything?

Comment: If the code comes from C++ STL v3.3 it obviously must have the grammar. This a template specialisation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ templates specialization syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323530/c-templates-specialization-syntax)

Comment: @Dan - Unrelated here

Comment: Sorry, I mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates?noredirect=1&lq=1) but now I can't change it.

Comment: @Dan - I've seen all of those. None seemed quite right. And I couldn't find a close enough dupe, to my amazement. So I think this one is now the canonical form for when someone asks about this "strage syntax".

Answer (score 0):

> Does C++ allow a template to be defined like "struct structname<..>"?

Yes, C++ has this syntax. It's defining a *partial* template specialization. So there is a primary `_STL_UNARY_FUNCTION_ERROR` template, that is defined somewhat like this:

```
template <class _Func, typename _Type, class _Arg>
struct _STL_UNARY_FUNCTION_ERROR {
  // ...
};
```

And the one you quoted gives a *specialized* version of it. When `_Type` is `void`, the resulting class will be defined (according to the remaining two parameters) as the one you have in your question.

> In the above example, what is the use of "<_Func, void, _Arg>"?

It specifies the arguments which will make this specialization be chosen when the template is instantiated. So whenever the second type is void, this is how the class will look.

> If we delete "<_Func, void, _Arg>", does it affect anything?

Yes. This will make the above a **redefinition** of the template. And the compiler is required to reject it. The effect is that your program is now ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a template (partial) specialisation. It changes how the template behaves when the middle template parameter is `void`

Somewhere above this there will be a declaration like

```
template <class _Func, class _Ret, class _Arg>
struct _STL_UNARY_FUNCTION_ERROR {
    static _Ret 
    __unary_function_requirement_violation(_Func& __f,
                                      const _Arg& __arg) {
    return __f(__arg);
  }
};
```

If you remove the `<_Func, void, _Arg>` you instead have a separate template, with the same name as a previous template, and your program is ill-formed.

Note that were `_STL_UNARY_FUNCTION_ERROR<_Func, void, _Arg>` to use the main definition, your program would be ill-formed, as you cannot have an expression in the `return` of a void function.