# Understanding the declaration, definition and specialization of templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to understand the below example, but I'm a bit confused from the three different template and struct declarations.

Could you please describe what will happen for the below call? which of the templates will be used and when?

Also why does the first template+class declaration is lacking "`<S...>`" right after the struct declaration?(**see what's commented out**)? when it's right to add it and when it's not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


template<typename... S>
struct Example /* <S...> */ ; 

template<typename H, typename... T>
struct Example<H, T...>
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(H) + Example<T...>::value;
};

template<>
struct Example<>
{
    static const size_t value = 0;
};


int main(){
    cout << Example<long, int, char>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output: 13**

Comment: The first part of the code (header excluded) is a _forward declaration_, without that, the compiler would not know the type `Example<T...>` that is used inside `Example<H, T...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also why does the first template+class declaration is lacking "< S...>" right after the struct declaration?(see what's commented out)? when it's right to add it and when it's not?

It seems to me that is better to start from this point.

First of all, the following (removed the `<S...>` commented) is a declaration (attention: declaration only, **not** definition) of a template struct `Example` that receive a variadic list of type template parameters

```
template<typename... S>
struct Example;
```

You can also avoid to use the `S` and write simply

```
template <typename...>
struct Example;
```

because the name of the variadic list isn't used in this context.

At this point the compiler know that there is a variadic template struct `Example` but doesn't know how is made.

Next we add the **definition** of a **specialization** of `Example` that receive one or more template parameter (observe that `Example` is defined to receive zero or more parameter, so a specialization that receive one or more parameter is special case of `Example`)

```
//....... one --> V          VVVVV <- or more template parameter
template<typename H, typename... T>
struct Example<H, T...>
{ // .........^^^^^^^^^  <- this is a specialization
    static const size_t value = sizeof(H) + Example<T...>::value;
};
```

The `<H, T...>` part after `Example` identifies a **specialization** (as said).

This specialization define a `static const size_t` variable initialized with the sum of the `sizeof(H)` (the `sizeof()` of the first type template parameter) with the `value` defined in another `Example` class: `Example<T...>`.

So you're observing a recursive definition: value is the sum of the `sizeof()` of the first parameter (a type) with the sum of the `sizeof()` of the following types.

Suggestion: if you use variadic templates, you can use also `constexpr`, so better define `value` as `constexpr`

```
 static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof(H) + Example<T...>::value;
```

Or better, you can inherit from `std::integral_constant`

```
template <typename H, typename... T>
struct Example <H, T...> 
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(H) + Example<T...>{}>
{ };
```

so you inherit `value` from `std::integral_constant` with additional useful facilities (by example: automatic conversion to `std::size_t` in a context where a `std::size_t` is required)

Every recursion needs a ground case, so you have

```
template<>
struct Example<>
{
    static const size_t value = 0;
};
```

the **declaration** of another **specialization** of `Example`; this time the case with exactly zero template parameter (`Example<>`). In this case you have the definition of a `value` that is zero to terminate the recursion.

As before, you can define `value` as `constexpr` or, better IMHO, using again `std::integral_constant`

```
template <>
struct Example<> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>
 { };
```

Now you have defined two specializations for `Example`: one for the one-or-more parameters cases, one for the zero-parameters case. So you have covered all cases for `Example` that is declared receiving zero-or-more parameters; there is no needs to declare the generic (not specialized version) of `Example`.

As observed by Deduplicator, you can **define** the generic case and only one specialization: if you write

```
template <typename...>
struct Example : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>
 { };

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct Example<T, Ts...>
 : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(T)+Example<Ts...>{}>
 { };
```

you first declare `Example` receiving zero-or-more parameters and define the generic case with a `value` zero (the ground case), next you define a one-or-more specialization.

Considering that the compiler select the more specialized version (when more version matches), the compiler select the specialization when there is one-or-more parameters (bot versions match but the specialization is more specialized) and the generic version when there are zero parameters (because the specialization doesn't matches).

This way is a little more synthetic but can be less clear.

> Could you please describe what will happen for the below call? which of the templates will be used and when?

Now should be simple to understand.

When you write

```
Example<long, int, char>::value
```

you ask for the `value` of `Example<long, int, char>`.

Three parameters, so the one-or-more specialization is selected, that is

```
value = sizeof(long) + Example<int, char>::value;
```

for the same reason, the `value` in `Example<int, char>` is

```
value = sizeof(int) + Example<char>::value;
```

and the `value` in `Example<char>` is

```
value = sizeof(char) + Example<>::value;
```

Now, for `Example<>::value`, the zero-parameters specialization is selected and `Example<>::value` is zero.

Concluding, we have that `value` in `Example<long, int, char>` is initialized with

```
 value = sizeof(long) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) + 0;
```

You tagged C++11, so it's a pity you can't use C++17 (template folding) where you can avoid recursion at all and define `Example` as a `using`

```
template <typename ... Ts>
using Example = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (... + sizeof(Ts))>;
```

Answer (score 8):

The first declares the template of a `struct` named `Example`, accepting any number of types:

```
template<typename... S>
struct Example /* <S...> */ ;
```

If the name of the newly declared template was followed by `<>`, with or without arguments, it would be a specialization instead!

The second defines a partial specialization for at least one type-argument:

```
template<typename H, typename... T>
struct Example<H, T...>
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(H) + Example<T...>::value;
};
```

And the last one defines a full specialization for no type-arguments:

```
template<>
struct Example<>
{
    static const size_t value = 0;
};
```

Take note that `template` is followed by empty `<>`-brackets.

It doesn't matter that the partial specialization is defined before the full specialization because instantiation must be deferred until the templates type-arguments are known.

The specific instance you use, `Example<long,int,char>::value`, depends on `Example<int, char>::value`, which depends on `Example<char>`, which leads to the base-case:

```
Example<long, int, char>::value = sizeof(long) + Example<int, char>::value; // sizeof(long) + sizeof(int) + 1 + 0
Example<int, char>::value = sizeof(int) + Example<char>::value; // sizeof(int) + 1 + 0
Example<char>::value = sizeof(char) + Example<>::value; // 1 + 0
Example<>::value = 0;
```

Of course, the example could be simplified:

```
template <class... T>
struct Example {
    static const size_t value = 0;
    static_assert(!sizeof...(T), "The base-template only handles no template arguments.");
};
template <class H, class... T>
struct Example {
    static const size_t value = sizeof(H) + Example<T...>::example;
};
```

Or with C++17 fold-expressions:

```
template <class... T>
struct Example {
    static const size_t value = 0 + ... + sizeof(T);
};
```

As an aside, there are good reasons never to use `using namespace std;`, I wonder why you `#include <stdio.h>`, and `return 0;` is redundant for `main()`.

Comment: In your simplified version, why does the base template only handle the empty case?

Comment: Yes, it handles only the empty case, and that's because putting the base case into the base template generally works out for the best. One could use helper-macros to make it the other way around, but that gets messy.

Comment: @Apollys both the base template and the specialisation match in non-empty cases, but the specialisation is picked. There are [specific rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for determining which is the "most specialised" match of a template for each instantiation.

Answer (score 6):

Only answering this part of your question:

> Also why does the first template+class declaration is lacking `< S...>` right after the struct declaration?(see what's commented out)? when it's right to add it and when it's not?

- When you make the **(general) declaration** of a templated function/class/struct/type, you only use the angle bracket`< >` once, before the declaration:

  ```
  template <typename T> 
  void foo(T x);
  ```
- When you declare a specific **instantiation** of the general template, you use `< >` twice, once empty before the declaration, then again with the specific template parameters for which you're instantating:

  ```
  template <>
  void foo<int>(int& x);
  ```
- When you declare a specific **specialization** of the general template, you use `< >` once, with the specific template parameters for which you're instantiating:

  ```
  template 
  void foo<int>(int& x);
  ```

More on the last two items (and how they differ):

[Difference between instantiation and specialization in c++ templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates)