# CMAKE auto header file dependency

Tags: linux, cmake

Question is similar to this question

[Handling header files dependencies with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461000/handling-header-files-dependencies-with-cmake)

I have sample program dir having main.c main.h and CMakeLists.txt

main.h contents are

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
int t=3;
int y=2;
#endif
```

main.c contents are

```
#include <main.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

  printf("%d apple",t);
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT( test )
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. test_SRCS)
include_directories(.)
ADD_EXECUTABLE (main ${test_SRCS})
```

but cmake is not rebuilding main.c on modification of header file. 
I want it to auto-generate header file dependency. 
Is it possible using cmake ?

if not is there any other tool which can do that ?

Comment: The dependency management is working fine for me for this example (using GCC and CMake 2.8.0 on Linux).

Comment: @antonakos  is it recompiling the project on modification of main.h header file ?

Comment: @antonakos  specifying minimum version as 2.8  it worked can you please put your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I have tried out your example and things were working fine: if `main.h` was modified then `main.c` would be recompiled.

My installation of CMake (version 2.8.0) told me to add

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
```

to the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but that is all of the adjustments I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this for others that google search...

I ran into this problem with one of my projects.  As it turns out I added the header to the cpp file after running cmake.  Re-running cmake fixed the problem.  If you run into this, try that and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

From the cmake 2.8.0 documentation of `AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY`:

> It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of source
>   files for a library or executable target. **While this seems to work,
>   there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a
>   new source file has been added.** Normally the generated build system
>   knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt file is
>   modified to add a new source. When the source is just added to the
>   directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>   rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

Why do you want to avoid creating a list of files? Such lists generally do not change frequently.

Comment: sorry to say but your answer is out of scope. What my question was cmake is not rebuilding the project on change of header files.

Comment: @VivekGoel - Crap, you're right. I misinterpreted it as applying to file modifications as well.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.