# CMake cannot figure out header dependencies if build is out-of-source?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I've been using CMake to manage a separate small c++ project (Unix Makefile based) and decided to convert it to a more organized out-of-source build. However when it's out-of-source (by doing a `cmake ..` in build/), my headers are no longer dependencies for their source files. If I just cmake from the top-level, everything is fine again.

So I've made a small test version and found the same problem. I'm on an Arch Linux system by the way. Originally, my project was in the /tmp directory (intentionally) and by reading this question: [Handling header files dependencies with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461000/handling-header-files-dependencies-with-cmake), I thought this could be the culprit because CMake might be seeing directories as system ones and hence thinking my headers are from system libraries, so I moved it to my home folder. Nothing changed. I then messed around with the paths in my CMakeLists.txt, but it didn't seem to change anything. I also tried replacing everything with absolute paths.

project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (MYTEST)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

file(GLOB SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
add_executable(app ${SOURCES})
```

project/src/hey.cpp:

```cpp
#include "hey.h"

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Heyyy" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

project/include/hey.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
```

Now if I make a new directory project/build and `cmake ..` from that directory then `make`, the project compiles. However if I change hey.h in any way and try to `make` again, nothing will recompile. The depend.make file is consistent with this:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.15

CMakeFiles/app.dir/src/hey.cpp.o: ../src/hey.cpp
```

But if I `cmake .` from the top directory `project`, everything goes well and the dependencies are all there:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.15

CMakeFiles/app.dir/src/hey.cpp.o: src/hey.cpp
CMakeFiles/app.dir/src/hey.cpp.o: include/hey.h
```

I have found people having similar problems, but most are edge cases and cause just one header not to be included. My actual project doesn't find any header dependencies. /: I could very easily just be using CMake horribly wrong (I'm sorta new to it), but I looked around and everyone seems to do it differently.

Comment: Can you try out two things? 1. make your build tree a sibling of your source tree (e.g. `cmake ../project`). 2. add also the header files to the `add_executable()` command. Does the problematic behaviour change if you do any of these?

Comment: @Angew Oh wow, yea making it a sibling fixed it thanks!, but why?

Comment: Isn't your situation described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741728/3440745) for the referenced question?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I thought it was, but I tried that solution with no success /:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your build directory is a subdirectory of the source directory, then it's not really out-of-source, but a sort of hybrid. The recommended CMake approach is to do proper out-of-source builds where the source and binary directory are totally unrelated. This means they can be siblings or further removed, but neither is a descendant of the other.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? I thought creating a build directory in the directory where CMakeLists.txt is located was the standard way to compile with cmake.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949212/cmake-not-handling-header-files-build-dependencies-if-build-dir-is-a-subdirector