# Cmake not handling header files build dependencies if build dir is a subdirectory of PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR?

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files

The accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167890/cmake-cannot-figure-out-header-dependencies-if-build-is-out-of-source/57168243#comment104645303_57168243) correctly states that cmake does not handle C++ header-files build dependencies in case cmake's build directory is under cmake's `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`. `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` is assigned its value when the cmake `project()` macro is used, therefore it would be the "top" directory for such a project structure using `project(source)`:

```
top
|
|--CmakeLists.txt
|--source
|--build
```

As far as I know, this is the typical structure of a cmake project, so I find it surprising that cmake does not handle this structure. Instead, such a structure would be required in order to handle the header file build dependencies correctly:

```
top
|
|--source
   |--CMakeLists.txt
|--build
```

Is this the expected behavior of cmake? Or is it a bug which should be reported?