# Boost Bimap takes too much memory in debug build

Tags: c++, boost, out-of-memory, bimap

I am using quite a few containers of the form

```
boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<std::string>, boost::bimaps::set_of<AnEnum> >
```

I am defining them in a header file that is included in quite a few cpp files (This is after I limited the exposure of the header file as much as possible). The .a files being created in the debug build runs to above 1 GB (resulting in compilation stopping midway due to 'no space on device' error and naturally the compile time has increased exponentially.

The compiler being used is gcc 4.8.1. Just wanted to know if anyone has encountered this problem with boost::bimap and what they did to resolve this issue

Comment: Are you using c++11 or c++98 ?

Comment: I am using gcc 4.8.1. I thought it automatically uses c++11. Am I wrong? Should I need to configure anything?

Comment: For me it works both with or without `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I is very likely that each time you use such a `bimap` in a different file, it is specialized leading to huge code duplication. If you are using `c++11` then you should declare them as `extern template`, And specialize it in only one file. See [using extern template (C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c0x)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Since there were lot of such maps, it took me time to make corrections and verify. But yes this method reduces the size significantly. Having said that I strongly recommend against using boost bimap unless absolutely required. In debug build my final application had a size of 110 MB with bimap and 35 MB without. In release it had a size of 33 vs 8. And this is after I was able to create the binary because I used the above method.