# Is there a way avoid having to instantiate a lot of templates in a lot of files?

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, instantiation

I'm writing cuda kernels that can make use of functors, that are passed as a parameter with templates. For example:

```
template<typename Functor> void myKernel(float arg1, float* arg2, Functor f) {
  // Do stuff that will involve f
}
```

These functors are defined in a header file that I include in each cpp file, and for each one I have to instantiate all the kernels with all the functors:

```
template<> myKernel<Add>(float, float*, Add)
template<> myKernel<Sub>(float, float*, Sub)
```

This is a lot of code duplication, and we have to remember to add a new line for each new functor.
Is there a way to define all of this once?

Comment: A preprocessor macro?

Comment: Are you aware of explicit instantiation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx

Comment: I hope that there is a solution that doesn't involve marcros.

Comment: It looks like you are defining specializations. Is that a requirement? Can you define one default template implementation instead, and then use implicit instantiation?

Comment: @jxh To use implicit instantiation I need to have my kernels defined in headers right? This is not an option: the functors are created in the cpp files, then given to the .cu files which are compiled separately.

Comment: Are you saying you are forbidden from defining a header file that all cpp files can include?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`extern template declarations.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c0x)

There are some subtle details about extern templates, especially 14.7.2.10:

> Except for inline functions and class template specializations,
>   explicit instantiation declarations have the effect of suppressing the
>   implicit instantiation of the entity to which they refer.

This means that the following will only suppress the instantiation of the non-inline member function f in other translation units, but not for g:

```
template<typename T> class A {
public:
     void g() {} // inline member function
     void f();
};

template<typename T> void A::f() {} // non-inline
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the instanciations in the header file, and you won't have to remember to specify them every time.