# Using extern template instantiation for nested types / typedefs

Tags: c++, templates, extern

Assume I have a class `Module<Setting>` that I want to instantiate externally. (reducing compilation time...)
I created a `Module.cpp` that contains `template class Module<Setting>;` and added the `extern` declaration in the header. This works fine.

Now I want to wrap this `Module` instantiation in another class, for example like this:

```
    template<template<typename> class M, typename First>
    struct TrivialInstantiator {
      typedef M<First> type;
    };
```

This does not seem to work, i.e. the compilation time for other compilation units does not change (in comparison to not using the extern declaration at all). My question: Why is that so? Can I somehow make it work?
(I tried to read the relevant sections of the standard, but I couldn't quite figure it out...)

Rationale for my question:
I have a larger number of Settings, and people may create new Settings that are not familiar with these details. If I simply create a list of extern template declarations for `Module<Setting1>`, `Module<Setting2>`, etc., this is not only tedious but will also tend to produce errors when users forget to add the template instantiation in the cpp file for example.
Therefore I tried to create a list of Settings (with `boost::mpl`) at one point and use this list of Settings to instantiate all of them at once.

Edit: This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c0x) is about how extern works altogether, it's not about how it handles nested types or typedefs.

Update: I read §14.7.2.8 several times again:

> An explicit instantiation that names a class template specialization is
>   also an explicit instantiation of the same kind (declaration or definition) 
>   of each of its members (not including members inherited from base
>   classes and members that are templates) [...].

I tried the following:

```
    template<template<typename> class M, typename First>
    struct TrivialInstantiator {
      M<First> member;
    };
```

As this does not work either: Is this member considered a template as in *not including members [...] that are templates*? (Isn't it a fully instantiated template that is something different...? Is there any way to workaround that?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using extern template (C++0x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c0x)