# Automatic constructor in explicitly instantiated class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a `template<bool VAR> struct Obj` template declared in a header file (`obj.h`) with explicit automatic move constructor (`= default`).

```
// obj.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>

template<bool VAR>
struct Obj {
  std::vector<int> member;
  Obj(int m): member(m) { }
  Obj(Obj&&) = default;
  int member_fun() const;
};

extern template struct Obj<false>;
extern template struct Obj<true>;
```

The member function of the template is defined in another file (`obj.cpp`) with explicit instantiation of the template:

```
// obj.cpp
#include "obj.h"

template<bool VAR>
int Obj<VAR>::member_fun() const {
  return 42;
}

template struct Obj<false>;
template struct Obj<true>;
```

This template is then used from the main file (`main.cpp`):

```
// main.cpp
#include <utility>
#include "obj.h"

int main() {
  Obj<true> o1(20);
  Obj<true> o2(std::move(o1));
  return o2.member_fun();
}
```

The `.cpp`s are then compiled and linked together with the following `Makefile`:

```
#CXX=clang++
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -std=c++14

a.out: obj.o main.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o a.out

obj.o: obj.cpp obj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
main.o: main.cpp obj.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

However, I get a linker error: `undefined reference to 'Obj<true>::Obj(Obj<true>&&)'` -- the compiler apparently did not instantiate the constructor.

- `Obj<true>::member_fun()` is defined and the program indeed links successfully if I remove the reference to the move constructor from `main.cpp`.
- If I remove `extern template` from the header, the program compiles.
- If I use `int` instead of `std::vector<int>` for the type of `member`, the program also compiles.
- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) claims that "the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit *inline* public member of its class". However, the manually defined `Obj(int)` constructor is also inline, but it is correctly instantiated.

(I received this error with Clang in a project that compiled fine with GCC, so I thought this was a Clang bug. However, when I reduced the problem to this simple case, both GCC 5.4.0 and Clang 3.8.0 produce the same results.)

Comment: Did the original project which was compiled with GCC use C++11 or still C++98?

Comment: It uses C++14 (`-std=c++14`).

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with explicit instantiation and inlining. Having a vector<int> probably makes the defaulted constructor non-inlined.

Comment: @skypjack: it is not necessary to define the template in the same file as long as every use of the template is instantiated in some object file in the program, which I accomplish with explicit instantiation in the `obj.cpp` file.

Comment: @rustyx yes, there is probably some interaction of templates, `inline`, and automatic definitions. However, cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) says that "... the compiler will declare a move constructor as a non-explicit *inline* public member of its class...". Note that the other constructor, `Obj(int)`, that I defined manually, is also `inline`, but it is defined in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting. I think your code is correct, because:

Your defaulted move-constructor is implicitly `inline` because of:

[[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default#5):

> ... A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly
>   defaulted after its first declaration) is defined at the point where
>   it is explicitly defaulted.

And [[class.mfct]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct#1):

> A member function may be defined ([dcl.fct.def]) in its class
>   definition, in which case it is an inline member function
>   ([dcl.fct.spec])

And thus is exempt from explicit template instantiation according to [[temp.explicit]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#10) (emphasis mine):

> **Except for inline functions and variables**, declarations with types
>   deduced from their initializer or return value ([dcl.spec.auto]),
>   const variables of literal types, variables of reference types, and
>   class template specializations, explicit instantiation declarations
>   have the effect of suppressing the implicit instantiation of the
>   entity to which they refer. [ Note: The intent is that an inline
>   function that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration
>   will still be implicitly instantiated when odr-used ([basic.def.odr])
>   so that the body can be considered for inlining, but that no
>   out-of-line copy of the inline function would be generated in the
>   translation unit. — end note ]

In fact, if you try any optimization mode other than `-O0`, the problem disappears.

`-O0` is a special mode in which inlined functions are not inlined. But it shouldn't matter, the compiler must in that case generate the `inline` defaulted move-constructor like it does with the other constructor.

So to me this looks like a compiler bug. Also look at [LLVM#22763](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22763) and [GCC#60796](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60796).

I see at least 2 possible workarounds:

**Solution 1**

Do not use `extern template ...` for now (compilation times will suffer but otherwise no big deal).

**Solution 2**

Trick the compiler into generating the suppressed constructor in `obj.cpp`

```
template<> Obj<true>::Obj(Obj&&) noexcept = default;
```

This one will only be used in `-O0` mode. In production code the inlined version will be used instead.

Comment: Solution 3: Define the move constructor out-of-line in one translation unit only. Header file: `Obj(Obj&&) noexcept;` Cpp file: `template <bool VAR> Obj<VAR>::Obj(Obj&&) noexcept = default;`

Comment: That will also work if you can get your compiler to inline across modules (my knowledge of this is limited, but at least GCC doesn't, even in -O3 mode). Otherwise this solution will impact performance of the production code.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't exist a lot of information about this topic on the internet. Though looking at some sources, I would conclude the following:

`extern template` should prevent implicit instantiations, though in all examples, the `explicit` instantiation doesn't have this `extern template` definition.

From what I can read, especially on the proposal and the GCC mailing list (see references below), the `extern template` doesn't prevent `implicit` instantiations, though ALL instantiations of the template. This would include your `explicit` instantiation.

> If an entity is the subject of both an explicit instantiation 
>   declaration and an explicit instantiation definition
>   in the same translation unit, the definition shall follow the declaration. - John Spicer on GCC mailing list

From this, I would conclude that you should remove the `extern template` in the translation unit where you want the explicit instantiation.

References:

- [SO: Using extern templace C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11)
- [Stroustrup: C++11FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#extern-templates)
- [Standard proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1448.pdf)
- [CppReference: Class Template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)
- [GCC Mailing list: extern template declaration accepted after explicit instantiation](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-12/msg02979.html)

Comment: If I understand you right, omitting the explicit instantiation declaration should allow the compiler to implicitly instantiate the member function definitions that it has seen when compiling `main.cpp` (i.e. the `inline` functions, including both constructors), while the explicit instantiation definition ensures that the non-`inline` members defined in `obj.cpp` will be generated properly?

Comment: I haven't tried it, though from what I can read, having the 'extern template' together with the explicit template results in the explicit being omitted. So you should drop the 'extern template' in that one translation unit which does that explicit template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are hitting a compiler bug.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60796.

I'm hitting similar behavior on CLang, but can't find a bug report.