# Extern template: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, extern

I have a template class

expof.h:

```
template <class T>
class ExpOf{
...
}
```

which I repeatedly use throughout my code for e.g. `T = double` [and other classes that `ExpOf` should not know anything about].
So I thought it would be a good idea to compile it once and for all [or twice...]

expofdouble.cpp:

```
#include "expof.h"
template class ExpOf<double>;
```

and declare it in a different header so it would not get compiled when expof.h is included.

expofdouble.h:

```
extern template ExpOf<double>;
```

When I compile this (clang-800.0.42.1) I get (numerous) warnings

```
expofdouble.h: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
extern template ExpOf<double>;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I getting the desired behavior? Why the warning then? Should I do this differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expofdouble.h` should contain this line:

```
extern template class ExpOf<double>;
```

Your declaration omits the `class` keyword, so it doesn't actually declare anything.

(Note that you'll get the same warning with a declaration like `extern int;`, which quite obviously doesn't do anything useful for you.)

Comment: Thanks, that was plain and easy after your comment.
I'm however getting a compiler-dependent linking time error due to the `template class` not instantiating an explicitly defaulted move constructor...
This seems to be a known bug of some compilers, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929950/automatic-constructor-in-explicitly-instantiated-class-template) in case it helps someone.