# Forward declaration of a template function from a seperate file

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

**other.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
std::ostream & cprint(T &t,  std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout){
    stream << msg << "\t{ ";
    for(typename T::iterator it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); it++)
        stream << *it << " ";
    stream << "}\n";

    return stream;
}
```

I have a template function in a separate file. and i am trying to forward declare it in **main.cpp** file.

```
extern template std::ostream & cprint<std::vector<int>>
(T &t,  std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout);
```

I have tried something as above but it didn't work for me.

**Edit:**
assume other.cpp has a basic function as below,

```
template <typename T>
void func(T x){
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

how to instantiate this function in main.cpp?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: You are not only doing it wrong, but whole idea is wrong, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @Slava Well, it's possible to put a template into a separate file if you manually specify all the types it must work for.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `'cprint' is not a template function` and `expected ';' before '<' token` errors i get.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yet it is, but looking into level of understanding from OP's question, this is not what he tries to do. And I bet next OP's question - why it does not work.

Comment: @Slava I guess I'm going to to write a short answer explaining that idea is wrong, but at the same time fixing the code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i am looking forward your answer. everthing seems pretty in logic. :(

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran I already gave you a link that explains why this not gonna work, do you mind read it?

Comment: @RıfatTolgaKiran See the edit. It turns out that `extern` was unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Keep in mind that what you're asking about is *(usually)* NOT the right way to work with templates.

**What you should do is to declare your template in a header and get rid of the `extern` declarations and explicit specializations.**

Putting templates into `.cpp`s usually isn't very convenient because they require you to specify all types you want them to work for in the same `.cpp`.

But, on the other hand, it improves compilation speed and there is a small chance that the resulting binary will be smaller.

---

#### How to fix your code:

I made some changes to your code to make it work.

I also made some minor improvements. Ask in comments if you find them confusing.

```
// 1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::ostream &cprint(const T &t, std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream &stream = std::cout)
{
    stream << msg << " { ";
    for(typename T::const_iterator it = t.cbegin(); it != t.cend(); it++)
        stream << *it << " ";
    stream << "}\n";
    return stream;
}

template std::ostream &cprint(const std::vector<int> &, std::string, std::ostream &);

// 2.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> std::ostream &cprint(const T &, std::string = "Container", std::ostream & = std::cout);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    cprint(v);
}
```

Important parts are following:

- Explicit instantination. It must be located in a same file as a template definion.
  `template std::ostream &cprint(const std::vector<int> &, std::string, std::ostream &);`
- Declaration. It must be in a file where you want to use your template.
  `template <typename T> std::ostream &cprint(const T &, std::string = "Container", std::ostream & = std::cout);`

Note that you can manually specify template arguments in explicit instantination and extern declaration if compiler can't deduce them.

---

Doing the same thing with a dummy template which was edited into a question is left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: You are right. I was totally doing it in a wrong way. i should have used an header and define everything in header.

Comment: The answer solves the problem, but I don't agree that template definitions only belong in headers or that their primary purpose is to decrease compilation time or binary size; in fact they can do the opposite, especially if they're defined in headers.

Comment: @gcbenison Point taken, edited the answer. I agree, sometimes putting templates into `.cpp` could be useful. The part about bettter compilation speed and small binary size was about templates located in `.cpp`s, *not* headers. I changed the wording to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), You  should also read: [using extern template (C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11)

To defer instantiation using `extern`, you must match the function signature exactly, so below will not work unless `T` is defined as `std::vector<int>` or its alias - which matches your template declaration.:

```
extern template std::ostream & cprint<std::vector<int>>
(T &t,  std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout);
```

To fix,

```
extern template std::ostream& cprint<std::vector<int>>
(std::vector<int>&, std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout);
```

See it [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ea581eab391e613)

More concretely,

*In **Header.hpp** file, I have its declaration and its deferment:*

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & cprint(T &t,  std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout){
    stream << msg << "\t{ ";
    for(typename T::iterator it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); it++)
        stream << *it << " ";
    stream << "}\n";

    return stream;
}

//defer instantiation
extern template std::ostream& cprint<std::vector<int>>
(std::vector<int>&, std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout);
```

Now, *in **main.cpp** file, I have:*

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cprint(v);
}
```

*In the **Header.cpp** file, I have its instantiation:*

```
template std::ostream& cprint<std::vector<int>>
(std::vector<int>&, std::string msg = "Container", std::ostream & stream = cout);
```

As seen [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a47f7bcf539cbe9)

=====================

**EDIT**: With respect to your recent edit:

> Edit: assume other.cpp has a basic function as below,
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> void func(T x){
>     cout << x << endl;
> }
> ```
>
> how to instantiate this function in main.cpp?

If the translation unit, *main.cpp* sees the declaration of the *function template* `func`(either from an included header, or you (re-(forward-))declared it in *main.cpp*, it will compile as calling a *function template-specialization*<sup>1</sup>, but the linker will be unable to find the *function template-specialization* unless it sees the definition of that *function template-specialization* as instantiated in (another) translation unit.

---

<sup>Note: "*function template specialization*" is a function instantiated from a function template. See [temp.fct/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.fct.spec#1)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you answered what OP asked?

Comment: @WhiZTiM i have edited the question to simplfy the solution. Even if i explicitly write all types compiler still gives errors.

Comment: @WhiZTiM `'cprint' is not a template function` error acording to your code