# C++: Is there any sense using the "extern" keyword for templates?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, instantiation, extern

Consider the following example:

fnc.h:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> //common template definition
void fnc()
{
    std::cout << "common";
}
```

fnc.cpp:

```
#include "fnc.h"

template<> //specialization for "int"
void fnc<int>()
{
    std::cout << "int";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "fnc.h"

extern template void fnc<int>(); // compiler will not generate fnc<int> and linker will be used to find "fnc<int>" in other object files

int main()
{
    fnc<double>(); //using instantiation from common template
    fnc<int>(); using specialization from "fnc.cpp"
}
```

Then I replace `extern template void fnc<int>();` with `template<> void fnc<int>();` and assume the behavior will be same. Is there any real meaning to using the `extern` keyword with templates or was it introduced for readability only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using extern template (C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not for specializations. Technically what you did is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. You have an explicit instantiation *declaration*, but no matching *definition*. The explicit specialization doesn't count for matching against the declaration you provided (even though some compilers implement it in a way that hides the fact).

This construct is for deferring instantiation, to make a compiler not try to instantiate the template in the current translation unit. So you may use it for hiding the template completely and exposing only for a finite set of types:

Header:

```
template <class T>
void fnc();

extern template void fnc<int>(); // The instantiation is elsewhere.
```

Source:

```
template <class T> //common template definition
void fnc()
{
    std::cout << "common";
}

template void fnc<int>(); // explicit instantiation
```

Or to prevent a frequently used specialization from being instantiated in every TU:

Common header:

```
#include <vector>
extern template std::vector<unsigned char>; // look for member definitions elsewhere.
```

One source file:

```
template std::vector<unsigned char>; // The member functions are defined in this TU
```

The later use case may save a on compile times.

Comment: Can't it also be used to "hide" (as in, prevent constant recompilation of) the most frequent instantiations of the template to reduce compile/link times?

Comment: @Max - Yeah that too. I'll rephrase