# How to structure explicit instantiation of a template for compilation speed?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I am specifically asking about file structure and where to put what. Consider the following (this is an example of my current structure):

**foo.h** consists of:

```
template <typaname T>
class Foo {
  void bar();
}

#include "foo-inl.h"
```

**foo-inl.h** consists of:

```
template<typaneme T>
void Foo::bar() {
}
```

Some **baz.cpp** has:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo<X> foo;
```

and some other **nom_test.cpp** has:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo<TestY> foo;
```

How do I restructure this to take advantage of the explicit instantiation in both the prod code (baz.cpp) and test code (nom_test.cpp). Mind, I wouldn't like to expose the test types to the prod build.

Comment: [using-extern-template-c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11) might interest you.

Comment: Is `Foo<X>` only occurring in `baz.cpp` or also in other files?

Comment: Potentially other files.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used

Answer (score 0):

**foo.h**:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  void bar();
}
#include "foo-inl.h"

extern template class Foo<X>; // means "Foo<X> is instantiated elsewhere"
```

**foo-impl.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"

template class Foo<X>; // instantiates Foo<X> here
```

**baz.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"
// can simply use Foo<X>, the impl will be linked from foo-impl.o
```

Similarly for the test build, **foo-impl-test.cpp** would contain:

```
#include "foo.h"

template class Foo<TestY>;
```

Keep in mind though that the semantics of explicitly instantiated templates is different - they are no longer `inline`! For this reason the usefulness of explicitly instantiated templates is limited. C++20 modules solve this in an entirely different and much more flexible way, so it might be worth waiting for that instead.

Comment: Potentially, `#include "foo-inl.h"` might be moved into cpp foo-impl.cpp and foo-impl-test.cpp

Comment: Yes, if you're sure you explicit-instantiate *all* possible `T`s.