# Why does extern template instantiation not work on move-only types?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, c++20, extern

The following code is ok:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

extern template class std::vector<int>;
template class std::vector<int>; // ok on copyable types

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v1 = std::vector<int>{}; // ok
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v2 = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>{}; // ok   
}
```

However, below is failed to compile:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

extern template class std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>;
template class std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>; // error on move-only types

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v1 = std::vector<int>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v2 = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>{};    
}
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/8qe94oGx5

***Why does extern template instantiation not work on move-only types?***

Comment: Which error did you get? What is the second line for?

Comment: The link is updated, and the error messages are in it.

Comment: may I ask why you even put the extern and template lines before main in your code? The includes and main should be enough

Comment: For faster compile speed. @PepijnKramer

Comment: Smells like premature optimization in this example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130602/using-extern-template-c11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicit instantiation definition (aka `template class ...`) will instantiate all member functions (that are not templated themselves).

Among other things, it will try to instantiate the copy constructor for the vector (and other functions requiring copyability), and will fail at it for obvious reasons.

It could be prevented with `requires`, but `std::vector` doesn't use it. Interestingly, Clang ignores `requires` in this case, so [I reported a bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/52625).