# separating constructor implementation with template from header file

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)

My header file has

```
template <typename T>
class AA : public BB<T>
{
public:
    AA()
    { ... }
```

this is working fine. But I need to separate the constructor implementation from header file.

So in cpp, I have

```
template <typename T>
AA<T>::AA()
{ ... }
```

When I compile this, it compiled but I get unresolved external symbol error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not recommended but you can go into your cpp and at the very end instantiate all possible templates like `AA<int> a; AA<double> c;` etc to resolve the link errors

Comment: You'll need to shop for a compiler that uses the Edison Design Group front-end.  The only guys that actually implemented external linkage on templates.  It is deprecated in the current C++ standard.  The most influential vote for the deprecation came from the Edison Design Group.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar I am not sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant OK. So this is not possible then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I really tried to find old question though.

Comment: @HansPassant: template names can (and usually) do have external linkage in the current C++ standard and that hasn't changed since the last standard. `export` and the concept of _exported_ templates, on the other hand has been removed (not deprecated) from C++11.

Comment: @Paul : There's no real harm in posting a duplicate, as long as you don't take offense to the question being closed. :-]

Comment: Well, that's indeed the proper verbiage.  But if *templates* had external linkage instead of template *instantiations* then it wouldn't be a universal problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly instantiate templates in your implementation file using :

```
template class AA<int>;
```

this will generate a definition from a template, but it is of use only if you know what types your class clients will use

Answer (score 2):

If you put a template implementation into a .cpp file you need to make sure that it gets instantiated: the compiler won't do it automatically for you. Roughly the same question was answered about a day ago: [do template always have to be in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662517)