# Templated Function definitions in seprate cpp file

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)
>   [Do template class member function implementations always have to go in the header file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662517/do-template-class-member-function-implementations-always-have-to-go-in-the-heade)

Ive made some stupid mistake here but i cant see what.

this compiles:

```
//start of header.h
namespace ns
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        template <class t>t func();
    };
    template<class t> t A::func()
    {
        t a;
        return a;
    }
}
//end of header.h
```

//start of imp.cpp

//end of imp.cpp

but the following does not:

```
//start of header.h
namespace ns
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        template <class t>t func();
    };
}
//end of header.h




//start of imp.cpp
#include "header.h"
using namespace ns;

template<class t> t A::func()
{
    t a;
    return a;
}
```

//end of imp.cpp

the error is :
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ns::A::func(void)" (??$func@H@A@ns@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: That's not a compiler error, but a *linker* error.

Answer (score 2):

Templates must be implemented in the header file since they cannot be compiled until they are instantiated.

See this answer:
[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file) .  There is other situation with template specialization - it is more like normal function (declaration in the .hpp , definition in the .cpp). If you want to have  a  specialization in the header you should remember to add inline (because of ODR).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule[ODR][1]