# how to implement into cpp file a member function MyClass<T>::MyMember<U>?

Tags: templates, generics, c++11

I am trying to put the implementation of a templatized member function f of a templatized class MyClass inside a .cpp (for security reasons) :

```
template < class T > class MyClass
{
public:
  template < class U > int f()
  { 
     /* ... */
     return 0;
  }
};
```

How do I put f() code into the .cpp file (instead of leaving it in the header file) ?

I tryied many things:

> template< class source_t > template< class U > int event_generator< source_t >::f< U >()
>
> template< class source_t, class U > int event_generator< source_t > ::f< U >()
>
> ...

Nothing worked, the recurrent error message : " `illegal use of explicit template arguments`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is (for the most part) that you cannot do that.

Actually, this is probably a duplicate question, see:

- [Templated Function definitions in seprate cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873588/templated-function-definitions-in-seprate-cpp-file)
- [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the)
- [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Another useful source:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

I recommend reading the above... It has an explanation of why you cannot separate it in general, but there are some specific situations when you can work around it.

Comment: It is not a linker problem or a the kind of problem found on these links. My problem is at the end more a syntaxic problem I guess ... or maybe this use precise use case is just not possible (yet) ?

Comment: @norisknofun: he points out that, once you syntax error were fixed, you would have to manage the link stage. if your type are really generic, you won't be able to hide implementation into a cpp.

Comment: I confirm : not possible !

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your first try, the syntax for the out-of-body definition of such member template would be

```
template<class T>
template<class U>
int MyClass<T>::f() {
 /* ... */
}
```

but as already pointed out, you cannot have that in a .cpp file - templates belong in the headers.