# Singleton C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I realise that there are already few topics like this on SO but I did not find any that would answer my problem.

I have already written my template singleton class using this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4750/Singleton-Pattern-A-review-and-analysis-of-existin

but unfortunately I keep on getting errors :

> /home/USER/testcode/cpp_workshop/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined
>   reference to `Singleton::Instance()' :-1: error: collect2: ld

my singleton.h

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& Instance();

protected:
    virtual ~Singleton();
    inline explicit Singleton();

private:
    static T* _instance;
    static T* CreateInstance();
};

template<typename T>
T* Singleton<T>::_instance = 0;

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

singleton.cpp

```
#include "singleton.h"
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename T>
Singleton<T>::Singleton()
{
    assert(Singleton::_instance == 0);
    Singleton::_instance = static_cast<T*>(this);
}

template<typename T>
 T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
    if (Singleton::_instance == 0)
    {
        Singleton::_instance = CreateInstance();
    }
    return *(Singleton::_instance);
}

template<typename T>
inline T* Singleton<T>::CreateInstance()
{
    return new T();
}

template<typename T>
Singleton<T>::~Singleton()
{
    if(Singleton::_instance != 0)
    {
        delete Singleton::_instance;
    }
    Singleton::_instance = 0;
}
```

and that's how I call it (with normall - not templated or anything - class `Game` )
`Singleton<Game>::Instance().run();`

Comment: Have you included the header file in main.cpp?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Yes I did include both of them (`game.h` and `singleton.h`)

Comment: Template function definitions must be visible to the compiler at the places where these functions are used. Therefore you cannot place them into separate `.cpp` file.

Comment: Btw, you should know that your singleton never gets deleted. Google "Meyers' singleton". You might also want to read the chapter on singletons from Alexandrescu's *Modern C++ Design*.

Comment: @PaulManta Can you explain why it never gets deleted ?

Comment: @Patryk The singleton object never goes out of scope, so the destructor is never called.

Comment: @PaulManta But doesn't it 'go out of scope' when the program end ? (when function main finishes)

Comment: @Patryk Yes, but only the pointer itself is destroyed. The data it points to (the singleton instance) never has its destructor called. Take a look at Meyers' singleton. It's a lot simpler and more robust than your current version.

Comment: How is your solution preventing me to do 'Game g; g.run();'?

Comment: @bmm constructor is protected.

Comment: But if Game's constructor is public, I will be able to write 'Game g;' So there can be multiple Game objects in the system. This Singleton class template cannot prevent it, right?

Comment: @bmm But here it's protected (maybe it would have been better to make it private) therefore you can't use `Game g;`.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, there is no Game class in this example. All operations are on template type T. I can define my own class MyGame with a public constructor. I still could not understand why it makes sense to use this singleton template pattern rather than embedding the Singleton pattern into my Game class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your method definitions under your class definition in the header, and delete your cpp. Templated methods and methods of templated classes must be defined in headers (with a couple hackish exceptions).

Per request, here are the 'hackish exceptions':

- 1) See @Desmond Hume's answer
- 2) Only use the templated class from the cpp in which the methods are defined. For example, you can declare/define a templated class in an unnamed namespace in a cpp, that's just fine.

Comment: It did compile with that :) Hopefully it will not cause any problems later on in runtime...

Comment: @Dave What those "hackish exceptions" would be?

Comment: @DesmondHume Edited to include them.

Comment: @Dave Seen your edit, hence another intrigue: since when the language's built-in feature is hackish?

Comment: @DesmondHume The exception you mentioned has always been considered hackish. Exception #2 is fine if it's all in an unnamed namespace, not hackish at all, otherwise I can't think of a legitimate use. It's 'fragile' at best (if anyone uses it from another translation unit it won't work). Thanks for the downvote btw.

Comment: @Dave Then C++ standard library must be "fragile" too? Quote: libstdc++ contains the explicit instantiation of std::basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> > (which is std::string) so every time you use functions of std::string, the same function code doesn't need to be copied to objects. The compiler only need to refer (link) those to libstdc++. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation

Answer (score 2):

You could put the definition of your `Singleton` class into the header file **or** you could keep the separation of declarations (the header) and definitions (the .cpp file) as it is now if you like it better and *explicitly instantiate* the `Singleton` class with each of the types you are going to use it with. To explicitly instantiate `Singleton` class, try putting the following at the end of the .cpp file:

```
template
class Singleton<Game>;
```

With another type it would look in the same way:

```
template
class Singleton<AnotherGame>; // just for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to separate the definiton (header file) and implementation (cpp) of a templated class.
So you have one of two solutions:

1- implement everything in the header file .h. something like this

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& Instance(){}

protected:
    virtual ~Singleton(){}
    inline explicit Singleton(){}

private:
    static T* _instance;
    static T* CreateInstance(){}
};
```

Another solution is to rename your .cpp class to .hpp. Don't include the .h file inside the .hpp file, but the other way around. i.e. include .hpp file inside .h file

I personally prefer the first solution

Cheers

Comment: "Its not accepted by the compiler" - this is not correct. There are 2 situations I know of which allow templated class's methods in cpps. 1) explicitly instantiating the class for the types you're going to use it with(see Desmond Hume's answer) 2) If the only place the template is used is within the cpp it's defined

Comment: Anyone can implement templated methods in .cpp files provided that the class the methods belong to is explicitly instantiated in that or some other .cpp file. It's even better in case of a static/dynamic library.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear, by implement I mean separating the header and implementation of templated class