# Explicit template instantiation - why is it needed?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Explicit instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation)

Why explicit template instantiation is needed?  Do I ever need it if I only use GCC and CLANG (and do not use MSVC)?

Comment: Why would the compiler choice matter?

Comment: @K-ballo --  I've encountered it only in context of MSVC use.

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit of information on SO already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation

Comment: @AndreiTita - there is information but no answer to my question that I am aware of.

Comment: [wikipedia to the rescue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extern_template) -- compile time improvements is a use for it in general in C++11.

Comment: @Yakk - I've would accepted this if this was an answer.

Comment: Explicit instantiation lets you create an instantiation of a templated class or function without actually using it in your code. Because this is useful when you are creating library (.lib) files that use templates for distribution