# C++ : Class templates, linker errors, and unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I've come across the following problem using templates (my IDE is Visual Studio 2012):

When I try to build my project, I get "unresolved external symbol" linker errors. I read that instead of separating my class between a header and source file, I should define everything in the header. However it still isn't working.

In the following example, I'm trying to create a class template for a "dictionary". It's supposed to pick up a type, and another type, and using two arrays create a "word" to "word" translation, if you'd use their common index. (Albeit "word" wouldn't be the exact description, I.E.: input[0] = 'A', output[0] = 2.5 -- this means the definition of 'A' is 2.5)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_H


template <class w, class d>
class Dictionary
{
public:

     Dictionary() ;//{}; // constructor (default)
    ~Dictionary() ;//{}; // destructor

    void Define(const w &st,const d &nd)
    {
        if(index < 100)
        {
            input[index] = st;
            output[index++] = nd;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr<<"Not enough space in dictionary.";
        }
    }// Define words using 2 parameters.st represents input, nd represents output (word -> translation)

    void print_words()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < index ; i++)
        {
            cout<<index<<". "<<input[i]<<output[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

private:
    w input[100];
    d output[100];
    static int index;
};
template <class w, class d>
int Dictionary<w,d>::index = 0;
#endif
```

The 'main' file is simply:

```
#include "Word.h"
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    Dictionary<int,double> a;
    a.Define(5,5.5);
}
```

And these are the errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Dictionary<int,double>::Dictionary<int,double>(void)" (??0?$Dictionary@HN@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Dictionary<int,double>::~Dictionary<int,double>(void)" (??1?$Dictionary@HN@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

What should I do to fix my code?

Comment: Oh. Ha. I see what you did there. I can't believe i missed something so simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Dictionary() ;//{}; // constructor (default)
~Dictionary() ;//{}; // destructor
```

You *declare* your default constructor and destructor, but do not *define* them.
That is, you tell the compiler you are writing these functions, so it goes looking for them, but you actually have *not* written them, so it gets upset.

Your options are (basically all the same thing):

- Remove these lines entirely, and get them generated by the compiler
- Remove the first comment slashes, and use an empty definition (`Dictionary(){}; // blah`)
- If you have a recent compiler (C++11 support), use the `default` keyword: `Dictionary() = default;`.

Also, in your header, *all* content of the file should be in the guards, (the `include` and the `using`). And I would strongly recommend you don't have `using namespace std;` in a header file (and I prefer never to use it at all). See [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191)

Comment: For completeness sake: another option is [explicit instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2351622/1227469), with the constructors defined in a source file (although this is probably not suitable for the OP's case as it seems he needs to be able to handle arbitrary types).

Comment: That's a very good solution. I'm just sorry i didn't notice my own errors before posting a question.