# How can I get my templated function to see other global methods defined later?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

(Oktalist gave a great answer below, check it out and the comments under it, to help demonstrate everything we've discussed, I've added a full, compiling solution at the bottom of my question that demonstrates everything discussed.)

I have a collection of namespace global methods and templated methods like the following:

```
namespace PrettyPrint
{
    String to_string(bool val);
    String to_string(char val);
    String to_string(int val);
    String to_string(uint val);
    // ETC...

    template <typename T> String to_string(const T* val)
    {
        if (! val) return U("NULL");
        return String().copy_formatted("(%p)-> %S", (const void*)val, to_string(*val).uchars());
    }

    // ... and more templates to help with containers and such
}
```

The "String" type is not the C++ string, it's a special class derived off of IBM's ICU library, but not really relevant for this question.  Point is, I have a bunch of namespace global methods called to_string and also some templated functions that override them.  So far, so good, everything works great.  But, now I have another header where I have something like the following defined:

```
namespace User 
{
    struct Service {
        int code;
        String name;
    }
    //...
}
namespace PrettyPrint
{
    String to_string(const User::Service& val) { return val.name; }
}
```

So, now I have defined some other type somewhere else, and I've also defined another to_string override in my PrettyPrint namespace to indicate how to convert my new type to a String.  Toss both headers into a file, something like this:

```
#include <the to_string and templates header>
#include <the User::Service header>

main() {
    User::Service s = {1, U("foo")};
    User::Service *p = &s;
    PrettyPrint::to_string(s);
    PrettyPrint::to_string(p);
}
```

(Yes, the to_string methods should actually be returning a value somewhere, not the point.) The point is that the second call gives a compiler error (gcc, btw) saying that in the templated to_string method there is no matching function for call to 'to_string(const User::Service&)', which of-course exactly matches my method that is defined and included. If I reverse the #include ordering it works just fine.

So, I surmise that the template is only looking at methods defined ahead of it.  Is there any fix for this?  Given the scope of my project and number of complicated #include's, simply saying "always make sure they come in the right order" is not a tractable solution, and would introduce too much complicated fragility in the code.  The base to_string defintions is one of those files that will tend to get included high up in a lot of places, so making sure that any other random type definitions that happen to include a to_string override come first just isn't going to work.

The other solution I have that works in some places is that I've defined a Printable interface in the base file:

```
namespace PrettyPrint
{
    class Printable {
    public:
        virtual String pretty_print_to_string() const = 0;
    }

    String to_string(const Printable& obj) { return obj.pretty_print_to_string(); }
}
```

That definition comes before the template methods in the same file.  So, that works great for classes where I can simply add in that interface and implement it.  Short of any great solutions here, I'm going to simply try to always use that, but there are places where it is not convenient and I'd also just like to understand if there is any way to get the method overloading solution to work without being dependent on #include ordering to work.

Anyhow, what do you all think of these options?  Is there an approach that I haven't thought of that might work nicely?

***Solution inspired from answer Oktalist gave***

This code actually does compile so you can copy it off and play with it, I think I've captured all the relevant use cases along with what works and what doesn't and why.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace PrettyPrint
{
    void sample(int val) { cout << "PrettyPrint::sample(int)\n"; }
    void sample(bool val) { cout << "PrettyPrint::sample(bool)\n"; }
    template<typename T> void sample(T* val) { cout << "PrettyPrint::sample(pointer); -> "; sample(*val); }
}

namespace User
{
    struct Foo {
        int i;
        bool b;
    };

    void sample(const Foo& val) {
        //below doesn't work un-qualified, tries to convert the int (val.i) into a Foo to make a recursive call.
        //meaning, it matches the User namespace version first
        //sample(val.i); doesn't work, tries to call User::sample(const Foo&)

        cout << "User::sample(const Foo&); -> {\n";
        cout << '\t'; PrettyPrint::sample(val.i); //now it works
        cout << '\t'; PrettyPrint::sample(val.b);
        cout << "}\n";
    }
}

namespace Other
{
    void test(User::Foo* fubar) {
        cout << "In Other::test(User::Foo*):\n";
        //PrettyPrint::sample(*fubar); //doesn't work, can't find sample(const User::Foo&) in PrettyPrint
        PrettyPrint::sample(fubar); //works, by argument-dependent lookup (ADL) from the template call
        sample(*fubar); //works, finds the method by ADL
        //sample(fubar); //doesn't work, only sees User::sample() and can't instantiate a Foo& from a Foo*
    }

    void test2(User::Foo* happy) {
        using PrettyPrint::sample; //now both work! this is the way to do it.
        cout << "In Other::test2(User::Foo*):\n";
        sample(*happy);
        sample(happy);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i=0, *p = &i;
    bool b=false;
    User::Foo f = {1, true}, *pf = &f;

    //sample(i);  <-- doesn't work, PrettyPrint namespace is not visible here, nor is User for that matter.
    PrettyPrint::sample(i); //now it works
    //PrettyPrint::sample(f); //doesn't work, forces search in PrettyPrint only, doesn't see User override.

    using namespace PrettyPrint;  // now they all work.
    sample(p);
    sample(b);

    sample(f);
    sample(pf);

    Other::test(pf);
    Other::test2(pf);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
PrettyPrint::sample(int)
PrettyPrint::sample(pointer); -> PrettyPrint::sample(int)
PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
PrettyPrint::sample(pointer); -> User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
In Other::test(User::Foo*):
PrettyPrint::sample(pointer); -> User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
In Other::test2(User::Foo*):
User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
PrettyPrint::sample(pointer); -> User::sample(const Foo&); -> {
    PrettyPrint::sample(int)
    PrettyPrint::sample(bool)
}
```

Comment: All functions which function template uses should be declared (possibly using [froward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)) before the point of template definition. You may also try to use [explicit instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used) if you exactly know what set of functions should be used by function template.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What you posted works just fine for me using g++-4.8.2. Could you provide an actual example?

Comment: @LucasB I wonder if the version of GCC you tried on was one of the versions that this (incorrectly) works on.  Check out the great link given by Oktalist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the first phase of two phase lookup, when the template is defined, *unqualified lookup* looks for dependent and non-dependent names in the immediate enclosing namespace of the template and finds only those `to_string` overloads which appear before the template definition.

During the second phase of two phase lookup, when the template is instantiated, *argument-dependent lookup* looks for dependent names in the namespaces associated with any class types passed as arguments to the named functions. But because your `to_string(const User::Service&)` overload is in the `PrettyPrint` namespace, it will not be found by argument-dependent lookup.

Move your `to_string(const User::Service&)` overload into the `User` namespace to make use of argument-dependent lookup, which will find any overloads declared at the point of template instantiation, including any declared after the point of template definition.

See also http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!  I'm not sure I really get it, it still feels to me like the function signature shouldn't match at all since I moved it to a different namespace, but I guess the namespace isn't really part of the type signature?  Anyhow, should point out that this works with classes, but not base types.  But that's fine, my base type overloads can all be defined in the primary file.  Thanks again for the excellent help!

Comment: Actually, now I'm getting a failure where I am calling: PrettyPrint::to_string(s); -- at least if that call happens to also be in the User namespace like it is with the code I'm testing this out on. Is this because it is explicitly scoped and so doesn't match, or because I'm in the same namespace and that is blocking the argument-dependent lookup?  If I make a to_string(const User::Service&) in both namespaces it works, though that seems a bit ugly. Slightly better I can define the method in one and "using" it into the other.  Still a little funky.

Comment: @DanielSkarbek ADL will not be used to find a function which is namespace-qualified. An idiom most often seen with [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable) is to put a using-declaration in local scope, followed by an unqualified function call: `void foo() { using PrettyPrint::to_string; to_string(User::Service()); }` Then ADL will be used, but if ADL finds nothing then it will try the one in `PrettyPrint`.

Comment: Awesome.  Excellent help once again.  Thanks very much!  So, basically the local scope using directive says to consider that namespace as an alternate place to look for anything in that scope.  If I have some other to_string in the User namespace, that would be picked first, but failing that, then it will look in the PrettyPrint namespace, and then in the global namespace, right?

Comment: Sorry, got it the wrong way round; the one in `PrettyPrint` will be used if present, ADL will only be used if none of the `to_string` overloads in `PrettyPrint` matches the argument(s). Global scope will not be considered (unless you add another using-declaration, `using ::to_string;`)

Answer (score 0):

What the compiler does when instantiating a template is essentially expanding it (more or less like a macro), and compiling the result on the fly. To do that, any functions (or other stuff) mentioned must be visible at that point. So make sure any declarations used are mentioned beforehand (in the same header file, most probably).

Comment: _"more or less like a macro"_ ... nooooooo!

Comment: @JonathanWakely, propose a different explanation if you don't like macros. AFAICS, it is expanding text with certain substitutions and compiling the result...

Comment: you can't explain two-stage lookup, dependent types etc in terms of macros. macros are pure textual substitution, outside the syntax of the language, templates are not. IMHO saying "like a macro" does more harm than good, better not to try to explain the instantiation model at all than to misrepresent it as something it isn't

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what's going on here, but it appears that if you want the later defined methods to be used, then they need to be template specializations.  The compiler won't see function overrides later in the program.

First off, we reproduce the problem.  I do so with this program in gcc-4.8.2:

```
// INCLUDE FILE 1
template <class T> void to_string (T const * a) {
  to_string (*a);
}
// INCLUDE FILE 1 END

// INCLUDE FILE 2
// How do we make this program work when this is necessarily declared after to_string(T const * A)?
void to_string(int const & a) {
  return;
}
// INCLUDE FILE 2 END

int main (void) {
  int i = 5;
  int * p = &i;

  to_string(i);
  to_string(p);
  to_string(&i);

  return 0;
}
```

In order to get it working, we need to do this...

```
// INCLUDE FILE 1
// The pointer version needs something to call...
template <class T> void to_string (T const & a);


// This can't be T const * a.  Try it.  So weird...
template <class T> void to_string (T * a) {
  foo (*a);
}
// INCLUDE FILE 1 END

// INCLUDE FILE 2
// This has to specialize template<> void to_string.  If we just override, we get a linking error.
template<> void to_string <int> (int const & a) {
  return;
}
// INCLUDE FILE 2 END

int main (void) {
  int i = 5;
  int * p = &i;

  to_string(i);
  to_string(p);
  to_string(&i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The point of the question was that I couldn't go back and declare my overload before the template.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this represents, and fixes, your problem.  The solution is to change your overload to a template specialization.  I wanted to post code that will actually compile without having to define classes it doesn't match your example exactly, so maybe it's a bit confusing.

Comment: But, your template specialization has to be of a template that is defined before the template method that is calling it. If I could make that happen, I could just put the normal overloaded method there. The point is that the type I want to use as an argument is not available when the base methods and templates are being defined.

Comment: You don't have to define the template method.  Just declare it.