# Understanding explicit instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I can't get the point why we should use explicit template instantiation. I thought it was used for exclitily specifying a family of classes/funtions/variables which would be used later in the program. So I tried the following example:
`main.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

U<int> u;

int main()
{
        cout << u.a << endl;
}
```

`test.h`

```
template<class T>
class U
{
public:
        int a = 10;
};
```

`Makefile`:

```
TARGET := bin

$(TARGET): main.o
        g++ -g -o bin main.o
main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -g -std=c++1y -c main.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.exe
```

And these program compiles, links and runs fine in spite of not using explicit instatiation. Couldn't you give an example where the explicit instatiation would be neccesary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used?rq=1

Comment: @T.C. So in my case the template was instantiated implicitly. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. It's obviously not instantiated explicitly.