# Template method implementation without <>

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++03

I have a template method in class:

```
template<class T>
    A& doSomething(T value)
```

Then I have an implementation

```
template<class T>
    A& A::doSomething(T value){
        // do something with value
        return *this;
    }
```

Then I have a specialization for lets say bool

```
template<>
    A& A::doSomething(bool value){
        // do something special with value of type bool
        return *this
    }
```

This is what I understand, now in the code there is something like this which I don't know what mean:

```
template A& A::doSomething(char const*);
template A& A::doSomething(char);
template A& A::doSomething(int);
template A& A::doSomething(int*);
template A& A::doSomething(double);
...
```

What is the exact meaning of those last 5 lines with template?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Explicit instantiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), which forces the instantiation of the templates with the specified template arguments, and prevents their implicit instantiations.

> An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the
>   function or member function they refer to. It may appear in the
>   program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given
>   argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the program.
>
> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents
>   implicit instantiations: the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided somewhere else in the program.

And see [Explicit instantiation - when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351148/3309790)

---

<sup>Because you tagged c++03, please note that `extern template` mentioned in the linked page was introduced from c++11.</sup>

Comment: There is no standard `extern` template with c++03

Comment: @Garf365 Added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now i see. I think the use case for this is to avoid undefined reference when you link to a library which has its templates implemented in cpp files. Am I right?

Comment: @Jan Yes, that is indeed a use case for explicit instantiation.

Comment: @Jan Yes, from the view of the library developer, you can restrict end user to use only the definitive versions. Use others will get a link error.

Comment: @Jan See [Explicit instantiation - when is it used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2351148/3309790) for the use cases of explicit instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

This lines aren't implementation. There only say to compiler to *"create"* code for `doSomething` for types `char const*`, `char`, `int`, `int *` and `double`

```
template A& A::doSomething(char const*);
template A& A::doSomething(char);
template A& A::doSomething(int);
template A& A::doSomething(int*);
template A& A::doSomething(double);
```