# C++ Template-styled function calling?

Tags: c++, function, void

I want my code to be clean and therefore I would like to achieve something like this:

```
Set<Color>(255, 255, 255);
Set<Opacity>(128);
Draw<Rectangle>(0, 0, 50, 50);
Set<Opacity>(255);
Draw<Texture>(Textures::Woman, 75, 75);
```

Basically multiple forms of a function for different names that are placed between the <>.

Would be great if it wasn't an actual template though, that would require me to code everything in .h files and I don't find that clean.

Comment: You can not use the `<>` syntax without templates, so its impossible to use this without templates. Note you can use explicit template instantiations so you don't need all code in your header file.

Comment: you can do the trick of implementing the template body in a .cpp file and then  include it into the header

Comment: What do you actually want to solve with this technique? Using mixin bases for property implementations? You should elaborate about your use case and show a complete (pseudo) code sample please.

Comment: It doesn't save the users of your API any typing, so why?

Answer (score 4):

How about using function overloads.

```
Set(Color(255, 255, 255));
Set(Opacity(128));
Draw(Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
Set(Opacity(255));
Draw(Texture(Textures::Woman, 75, 75));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just overload the functions (assuming that the signature is different every time, which they are in your case)?

```
//set color
void Set(int r, int g, int b) {}

//set opacity
void Set(int op) {}

//draw rectangle
void Draw(int x, int y, int w, int h) {}

//draw image
void Draw(Texture tex, int w, int h) {}
```

*Note: Making individual functions (`SetColor`, `SetOpacity`) would make the code much clearer than those overloads which have nothing to do with each other, so you should consider using that instead.*

Comment: The drawback with the example code is, that such an interface does not give any semantic information on the caller side. What exactly does `Set(42, 17, 32);` set?

Comment: @cdonat true, you could however interpret the arguments (`r`, `g` and `b` -> that has to be a color). But I agree, this is not the best way.

Comment: At the caller side, you don't see the parameter names, when you read the code.

Comment: @cdonat only if you're using a good enough IDE, but if you are not using one, stick with Loki's answer or my alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use tags:

```
//set color
void Set(Color_tag, int r, int g, int b) {}

//set opacity
void Set(Opacity_tag, int op) {}

//draw rectangle
void Draw(Rgectangle_tag, int x, int y, int w, int h) {}

//draw image
void Draw(Texture_tag, Texture tex, int w, int h) {}
```

In order this to work, you will need also:

```
struct Color_tag{};
struct Opacity_tag{};
struct Rectangle_tag{};
struct Texture_tag{};

Color_tag color;
Opacity_tag opacity;
Rectangle_tag rectangle;
Texture_tag texture;
```

then your code will look like:

```
Set(color, 255, 255, 255);
Set(opacity, 128);
Draw(rectangle, 0, 0, 50, 50);
Set(opacity, 255);
Draw(texture, Textures::Woman, 75, 75);
```

This way of working is very powerful, it will allow to have something like this:

```
//set color
void Set(Color_tag, int r, int g, int b) {}

//set Hex color (HTML style)
void Set(Color_tag, int color) {}

//set opacity, same parameters like set hex color
void Set(Opacity_tag, int op) {}
```

However I like more normal overloads similar to what Blitz Rakete suggested.

Comment: The OP can just as well pass the tag type as a template parameter...

Answer (score 0):

What's unclean about creating the methods SetColor(int,int,int), SetOpacity(int), etc? If you want simplicity in your headers you could write macros to streamline get/set creation.

e.g.

```
#define SYNTHESIZE(TYPE, VARNAME, FUNCNAME) \
protected: TYPE VARNAME;\
public: virtual TYPE get##FUNCNAME(void) const { return VARNAME; }\
public: virtual void set##FUNCNAME(TYPE var){ VARNAME = var; }
```

Use

```
class Foo
{
   SYNTHESIZE(float, bar, Bar);
}
```

As @tobspr says you can't use the < > syntax without using templates or modifying the compiler. There are however ways to specialise a template so you can define it in a cpp instead.

See: [Explicit instantiation - when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a template parameter, have a single parameter that encodes the specific kind of action in its type.

```
class Color {
    private:
        uint8_t r_;
        uint8_t g_;
        uint8_t b_;
    public:
        Color(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b):
            r_{r}, g_{g}, b_{b} {};
};

class Opacity {
    private:
        uint8_t alpha_;
    public:
        Opacity(uint_8 alpha): alpha_{alpha} {};
};

class Rectangle {
    private:
        uint32_t x_;
        uint32_t y_;
        uint32_t w_;
        uint32_t h_;
    public:
        Rectangle(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t w, uint32_t h):
            x_{x}, y_{y}, w_{w}, h_{h} {};
};

// etc.
```

And then use a function overload instead of a template.

```
class Context {
    public:
        Set(const Color& c);
        Set(const Opacity& o);
        Draw(const Rectangle& rect);
        // etc.
}
```

The usage is at least very close to what you try to achieve.

```
Set(Color{255, 255, 255});
Set(Opacity{128});
Draw(Rectangle{0, 0, 50, 50});
Set(Opacity{255});
Draw(Texture{Textures::Woman, 75, 75});
```

You also might like to have different Rectlangle constructors, one with two points and one with a point and width and height. There you can use the same strategy:

```
class Width {
    private:
        uint32_t w_
    public:
        Width(uint32_t w): w_{w} {};
        operator uint32_t () { return w_; };
};
class Height {
    // same as Width
};

class Rectangle {
    private:
        uint32_t x1_;
        uint32_t y1_;
        uint32_t x2_;
        uint32_t y2_;
    public:
        Rectangle(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, Width w, Height h):
            x1_{x}, y1_{y}, x2_{x+w}, y2_{y+h} {};
        Rectangle(uint32_t x1, uint32_t y1, uint32_t x2, uint32_t y2):
            x1_{x1}, y1_{y1}, x2_{x2}, y2_{y2} {};
};

// usage
Draw(Rectangle{0, 0, Width{50}, Height{50}}); // use width and height
Draw(Rectangle{0, 0, 50, 50}); // use two points
```

You can even go further and define a Point type, so that drawing a rectangle will look like this:

```
Draw(Rectangle{Point{0, 0}, Width{50}, Height{50}}); // use width and height
Draw(Rectangle{Point{0, 0}, Point{50, 50}}); // use two points
```

Use techniques like that to find the perfect balance between stating of intent and reducing noise.

And of course you can add simple template functions to your Context:

```
template<typename T, typename A...>
Set(A&& args...) {
    Set(T{std::forward(args)...});
}

template<typename T, typename A...>
Draw(A&& args...) {
    Draw(T{std::forward(args)...});
}
```

Now you can use the whole machine as you originally intended.

```
Set<Color>(255, 255, 255);
Set<Opacity>(128);
Draw<Rectangle>(0, 0, 50, 50);
Set<Opacity>(255);
Draw<Texture>(Textures::Woman, 75, 75);

// With width and height types
Draw<Rectangle>(0, 0, Width{50}, Height{50});
Draw<Rectangle>(0, 0, 50, 50);
// With Point Type
Draw<Rectangle>(Point{0, 0}, Width{50}, Height{50});
Draw<Rectangle>(Point{0, 0}, Point{50, 50});
```