# Explicit Instantiation Not Working Properly

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I'm encountering a strange bug. I appear to be using explicit instantiation properly, however I am getting an "unresolved external symbol" error when compiling.

Here is what is happening:

**code.h**

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
struct A {
    void foo() const;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A<T> {};

typedef B<int> C;
```

**code.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"

template <typename T>
void A<T>::foo() const {}

template struct B<int>;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "code.h"

int main() {

    C test;
    test.foo()  // <----- unresolved external symbol

    return 0;

}
```

As far as I can tell, I'm doing almost exactly what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2351622/4981832) is doing, except with inheritance thrown into the mix. Why is this erroring? If it helps, I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you look here in **code.h**:

```
template <typename T>
struct B : public A<T> {};
```

You see that I am using `A<T>`, which also needs to be explicitly instantiated.