# Template Inheritance issues

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have an Abstractqueue and I want to inherit it's members to another child class. When I try to create the child object in my main file I keep getting an undefined reference to `AbstractQueue::AbstractQueue()'

```
enter code here
#ifndef ABSTRACT_QUEUE_H
#define ABSTRACT_QUEUE_H

#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
class AbstractQueue
{
protected:
    Type *items;
    int front;
    int back;
    int capacity;
    int count;
private:
    // data goes here

public:
    AbstractQueue(int s);

   AbstractQueue(void);

   ~AbstractQueue(void);

   bool empty();

   int size();

   Type frontele(); //throw(exception) {}

   Type dequeue(); //throw(exception) {}

   void enqueue ( Type e );
};

template <class Type>
AbstractQueue<Type>::AbstractQueue(int s){
    items = new Type[s];
    front = 0;
    back = 0;
    capacity = s;
    count = 0;
    std::cout << "made the abstract queue!" << std::endl;

}

template <class Type>
AbstractQueue<Type>::~AbstractQueue() {
    delete[] items;
    std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

IncrementalQueue.h

```
#ifndef _INCREMENTALQUEUE_H
#define _INCREMENTALQUEUE_H

#include "Queue.h"

//#define SIZE = 10

#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
class IncrementalQueue : public AbstractQueue<Type>{

    public:
        //AbstractQueue(void);

       //~AbstractQueue(void);

       IncrementalQueue(int s);

       bool empty();

       int size();

       Type frontele(); //throw(exception) {}

       Type dequeue(); //throw(exception) {}

       void enqueue ( Type e );



    //~IncrementalQueue(void);



    //AbstractQueue(void);

    //AbstractQueue(int size);

    //bool empty(void) ;
        /*if (count == 0) {
        return true;
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }*/

    //int size(void);

    //Type front throw(exception) {}

    //Type dequeue(); //throw(exception) {}

    //void enqueue ( Type e ) ;

        //IncrementalQueue(int size);
};
template <class Type>
IncrementalQueue<Type>::IncrementalQueue(int s){
    this->items = new Type[50];
    this->front = 0;
    this->back = 0;
    this->capacity = 50;
    this->count = 0;
    std::cout << "made the incremental queue!" << std::endl;

}


#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include "IncrementalQueue.h"

int main(){

    IncrementalQueue<int> incqueue(50);


    return 0;
}
```

I'm a little rusty with templates so I've been struggling at it for a couple of hours. does anybody have any clues on where my code can be failing?

Comment: 1) Where is the definition for `AbstractQueue::AbstractQueue ()`? I only see a declaration of it. 2) Note, templates have nothing to do with it. One would be able to reproduce the same problem with non-template classes.

Answer (score 2):

`IncrementalQueue::IncrementalQueue()` constructor is calling the `AbstractQueue::AbstractQueue()` constructor and you have not defined it.

To make it compile you can just say `AbstractQueue() = default;` to have it generated by the compiler, if you are using `C++11` or later, **but** that will not necessarily be correct (see the comments).

Comment: default one is currently "wrong" BTW, as all members would be uninitialized. It could be fixed by also adding `= 0` to each members.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes, v good point, I was only focusing on the compilation issue,I updates the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it always happens with templates, you either need to put `AbstractQueue::AbstractQueue()` implementation (function body) to its header, or, if you know in advance all its possible template parameters, [explicitly instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used) this function in cpp-file:

`template class AbstractQueue<NeededType>;`

In your case, it's impossible to know all possible template args in advance, so you need to put your function body to the header. That's the price of separate unit compilation.