# c++ assigment operator with two or more template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Code example :

```
#include <cstdio>

class Test
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename T2>
    bool operator =(T& value)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template bool Test::operator= <int, bool>(int&);

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int gg = 1234;
    t = gg;
}
```

Checked several compilers. Problem with line t=gg.
If i remove second template argument T2, Everything compiles and works. Is it not allowed to have several template argumens for assigment operator?

Comment: Question: Why do you need 2 template parameters? The second one doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: what's the second parameter for? The compiler needs something to deduce the template parameters from, as you aren't using the second parameter it can't deduce its type

Comment: `t.operator=<int, void>(gg);` ? ;-)

Comment: Imagine that in operator i create object of type T2 and put it some list. I did not show full source code, because problem can be seen from this part

Comment: This looks like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. something that has a better solution. Please make your code snippet complete so we can actually see what you are trying. Because the solution for your current question is: "*Remove the second template argument.*" On first sight, this looks like it might be an abuse of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 5):

You may use as many templates parameters as you need.

The problem is that the compiler does not have a means to deduce other template parameters except the template parameters that are specified in the declaration of the operator parameter or that have a default argument.

So you will have to write something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename T2>
    bool operator =( T& )
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template bool Test::operator= <int, bool>(int&);

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int gg = 1234;
    t.operator =<int, bool>(  gg );
}
```

Comment: Its true, i did know about that. The idea was that, that if asign int, operator lets say always creates object bool. And if assign bool, then it creates always Int for example. I thougt that it possible to do with class function specelization.It should be that one type should create another type, and should be 1 to 1 mapping. If i have hunderd types so will need hunderd different functions and with templates it would be one line. I thougt it is possible

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not allowed to have several template argumens for assigment operator? [sic]

It's not that it's not allowed, but rather that the compiler has no way to deduce the second argument.

If your function looked something like this:

```
template<typename T>
    bool operator =(T& value)
```

Then template parameter `T` could be deduced: It will be the type of whatever you're trying to set `t` to. Since this is all the template parameters, you're good.

However, what happens when you have 2?

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
    bool operator =(T& value)
```

`T` is easily deducible, but what about `T2`? How would the compiler know what `T2` should be? The answer is it can't.

You do have the option of telling it, by calling the operator function directly:

```
t.operator=<int, bool>(gg);
```

But I would imagine that wouldn't be what you want.

Unfortunately for you, the following expression won't work:

```
t =<bool> gg;
```

So I think calling `operator=()` directly is your only option here.

---

> Imagine that in operator i create object of type T2 and put it some list. I did not show full source code, because problem can be seen from this part

It sounds like you're using the `operator=()` for something it wasn't designed to do. `operator=()` is really only supposed to be used for copying the other object's state. If everything you need to set your state isn't inherent in the `T`, then you probably shouldn't be using `operator=()` for this purpose.

Consider splitting it into two separate functions, or move it into a non-operator function altogether. This way, it will be more clear to other people reading your code in the future what it is you're doing anyway.

Comment: as i understand, i should somehow disable automatic compiler template parameter deduction. I thought that line template bool Test::operator= <int, bool>(int&); will do that but it looks, that compiler tries to find answer by it self.

Comment: @MindasMindas - you have to remember that the compiler is *required* to deduce what template instantiation is required from thec expression itself.   There is no information in the expression `t = gg` for it to deduce the second template parameter.    The fact you have explicitly instantiated the `operator=<int, bool>` does not mean that the compiler is required to look at it as a match for the expression `t  = gg`.   It means that, IF the compiler deduces that `Test::operator=<int, bool>` is a match then there will be an explicit instantiation to be called.

Comment: @MindasMindas, so after a closer look, I realize you might be trying ["explicit instantiation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-instantiation-when-is-it-used), but you're not doing it right. With explicit instantiation, it looks for an implementation of that function in a source file. Come to think of that, you might want to try putting your source in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I really don't understand what you want to achieve, and I absolutely agree wit hte others, that you're probably trying doing something with the assignment operator that it's not intender for.

But here's a piece of code that is at least syntactically close to your requirement. Instead of specifying the two parameters in the operator declaration, you could make `Test` a class template and use plain old function overloading.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Test {

    T2 operator=(T1&) { return {}; }
    T1 operator=(T2&) { return {}; }
};

struct Foo {};

int main() {

    Test<int, Foo> t;

    int gg = 1234;
    Foo x = t = gg;  // <- this really looks weird, but works.

    Foo ff;
    int i = t = ff;

}
```

If this is not what you want, then we proably need more information about your comcreate use case.

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/uVN68D).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you actually want to do is derive a second type from your first template argument. This would normally be achieved through some sort of traits type:

```
#include <cstdio>

template < typename T >
struct TestTraits;

template <>
struct TestTraits< int >
{
    typedef bool T2;
};

class Test
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    bool operator =(T& value)
    {
        using T2 = typename TestTraits< T >::T2;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int gg = 1234;
    t = gg;
}
```