# Can my code benefit from explicit template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a generated class, that provides access to a database and maps the field values for each row with the field names for that column. We use it to avoid typing mistakes in the queries and write code like `for(auto& entity: db.table1) { doSomething(entity.field1()); }`.

However, each CPP file that includes this header starts to compile slow, generates a big object file (~14 MB) and causes very long linker times (GCC on Windows).

Here's a very shortened version of this class structure. Is there any way to speed up my linker times?

```
// MyDatabase.hxx
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
// this template is a generic header
template <class TableData> class Table {
public:
    TableData getFirstRowFromDatabase() {return m_rows.begin();}
    // following many, very complex member functions
    std::vector<TableData> m_rows;
};

// this class declaration is generated by a program by parsing the SQL schema
class MyDatabase {
public:
    // Data structure holding the fields of a table and relationship to database names
    class Data1 /*: public BaseEntity */ {
    public:
        int i;
        struct TEXT {
            const char* i()const {return "i";}
        };
        // bool readFromDatabase() overrides {...}
    };
    class Data2 {
    public:
        double d;
        // ...
    };
    // ... many more Data definitions here ...
    Table<Data1> m_data1;
    Table<Data2> m_data2;
    // ... many table members here
};
// try to avoid an instance of MyDatabase in any other CPP file
std::shared_ptr<MyDatabase> openDatabase();

// MyDatabase.cpp
// #include "MyDatabase.h"
std::shared_ptr<MyDatabase> openDatabase() {
    return std::make_shared<MyDatabase>();
}

// main.cpp
// #include "MyDatabase.h"
int main() {
    auto table = openDatabase();
}
```

[edit] changed title, thank you.

Comment: It's explicit template *instantiation* you need, not specialization.   For some discussion that is relevant to your question, have a look at answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used

Comment: Changed title, thank you.

Comment: It may help if you use `Table<T>` for the same `T` in more than one source file. But if `T` is always different, then there will be little difference. In addition, explicitly instantiated methods are more difficult to inline, so the resulting code may become slower.