# template specialization in header causes Linking issues

Tags: c++, c++17

I am playing around with converting standard library functions like `stoi` to not throw exceptions on failures but keep running into linking issues. I followed steps from other similar questions but the linker is still not satisfied

Header.h

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
namespace temp{
    template<class T>
    std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi( const T& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10)
    {
      //body of the function 
    }
    template<> inline std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::wstring>( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
    template<> inline std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::string>( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
int main(){
  std::string input = "123";
  auto result = temp::safe_stoi(input);
return 0;
}
```

Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"std::__1::optional temp::noexcept_stoi<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, unsigned long*, int)"

What am I missing ?

Comment: You just declared specializations, not defined them.

Comment: @AnoopRana Why do you think the OP wants explicit template instantiations? Their question title says "template specialization", and their syntax is a template specialization. It's not an *unreasonable* assumption, but in that case your answer should explain the difference between the two things, primarily, to clear up the confusion.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I have updated my answer to include both ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The **problem** is that you have only provided the declarations for the specializations and not the corresponding definition. There are two ways to solve this as given below:

##### Method 1

Here we provide the corresponding definition for the specializations.

```
namespace temp{
    template<class T>
    std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi( const T& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10)
    {
      return 4; //don't forget to return something
    }
    template<> inline std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::wstring>( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos, int base )
    {
        return 4;
    }
    template<> inline std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::string>( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos, int base )
    {
        return 4;
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SijbPqTmuPMSzrwZ)

##### Method 2

We could make use of [explicit template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used) to solve this problem as shown below.

**Header.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
namespace temp{
    template<class T>
    std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi( const T& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10)
    {
      return 4; //return something
    }
//-----------------v------------------------->no need for angle brackets as well as inline 
    extern template  std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::wstring>( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
//-----------------v------------------------->no need for angle brackets as well as inline
    extern template  std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::string>( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
//explicit template instantiation definition
template  std::optional<int> temp::noexcept_stoi<std::wstring>( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
template  std::optional<int> temp::noexcept_stoi<std::string>( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );
int main(){
  std::string input = "123";

  auto result = temp::noexcept_stoi(input);
return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r78stTOIRtqjOlP4)

Comment: TIL. I was absolutely sure that explicit instantiations counted as ordinary functions for this purpose. Seems I was wrong. But I strongly question the *point* of putting explicit instantiation definitions (as opposed to declarations that start with `extern`) into headers. That would actually increase the compiler's work, not decrease it.

Comment: Gents, can you point the exact point in the standard that allows it?

Comment: OK, I've done some more reading: my main concenrn was this part (in method 2) `template  std::optional<int> noexcept_stoi<std::wstring>( const std::wstring& str, std::size_t* pos, int base );` possibly violating ODR, but it's no problem due to `noexcept_stoi` being inline, is that the case?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Actually if the header is included in more than one source files we will have UB. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template): *"An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the class, struct, or union they refer to. It may appear in the program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the entire program, no diagnostic required."* I have used `extern` in my updated method 2.

Comment: @alagner If the header in method 2 is included in more than one source file then it will be ill-formed. So i have updated method2 to use explicit template instantiation declaration using `extern`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) *"An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the class, struct, or union they refer to. It may appear in the program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the entire program, no diagnostic required."*

Comment: In N4901, that's 13.9.1/5. Nice to see that I did remember the rules correctly, even if I didn't remember the consequences correctly.