# What does "template class" keyword in C++ do?

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++ and am self-learning the [databases course at CMU](https://15445.courses.cs.cmu.edu/fall2022). In the second programming project, we implement a B+ tree index. We have a `BPlusTreePage` class which has two children class `BPlusTreeInternalPage` and `BPlusTreeLeafPage`. The way the skeleton code handles generic class confuses me.

In `b_plus_tree_internal_page.h`:

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType, typename KeyComparator>
class BPlusTreeInternalPage : public BPlusTreePage {...};
```

In `b_plus_tree_internal_page.cpp`:

```
...
// valuetype for internalNode should be page id_t
template class BPlusTreeInternalPage<GenericKey<4>, page_id_t, GenericComparator<4>>;
template class BPlusTreeInternalPage<GenericKey<8>, page_id_t, GenericComparator<8>>;
template class BPlusTreeInternalPage<GenericKey<16>, page_id_t, GenericComparator<16>>;
template class BPlusTreeInternalPage<GenericKey<32>, page_id_t, GenericComparator<32>>;
template class BPlusTreeInternalPage<GenericKey<64>, page_id_t, GenericComparator<64>>;
```

I'm wondering what does these lines starting with `template class` do? In my understanding, the code should just work without those lines, but I'm not sure if I'm correct. Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's called explicit template instantiation.  Check out *[Class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)* and *[Explicit template instantiation - when is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351148/explicit-template-instantiation-when-is-it-used)*

Comment: Thanks! That really clears my confusion.

Comment: (out of scope): A strange program of learning the C++ language -- in the second project, the study of templates is already underway...

Comment: @SergeRoussak It's a database course, not C++ course.