# Tool to analyze size of ELF sections and symbol

Tags: c, parsing, gcc, cross-compiling, objdump

I need a way to analyze output file of my GCC compiler for ARM. I am compiling for bare metal and I am quite concerned with size. I can use `arm-none-eabi-objdump` provided by the cross-compiler but parsing the output is not something I would be eager to do if there exists a tool for this task. Do you know of such a tool existing? My search turned out no results.

One more thing, every function in my own code is in its own section.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What kind of information do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use `nm` and `size` to get the size of functions and ELF sections.

To get the size of the functions (and objects with static storage duration):

```
$ nm --print-size --size-sort --radix=d tst.o
```

The second column shows the size in decimal of function and objects.

To get the size of the sections:

```
$ size -A -d tst.o
```

The second column shows the size in decimal of the sections.

Comment: `nm`, isn't that Windows? If so, sorry - I did not say I am using Linux.

Comment: Windows? No, `nm` and `size` are GNU tools part and are a part of the `binutils`. Add the required platform prefix to run the tools in a cross platform (e.g., type `arm-none-eabi-nm` and `arm-none-eabi-size`),

Comment: Interestingly, this also has the size-effect of removing ARM's [Mapping Symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/ARM-Mapping-Symbols.html). These symbols are printed without a size field (i.e. the field is missing, not printed as zero), and they are removed when `nm` is used with `--size-sort`.

Comment: @ouah But the total section size of nm output doesn't equal to file size. What's missing here ?

Answer (score 11):

The [readelf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) utility is handy for displaying a variety of section information, including section sizes, e.g.:

```
arm-none-eabi-readelf -e foo.o
```

If you're interested in the run-time memory footprint, you can ignore the sections that do not have the 'A' (allocate) flag set.

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-readelf -s build/program.out|perl -ne 'if(/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) { print $3 . " " . $8.  "\n";}'|sort -n`

Comment: Thank you, the above did the trick for me! I did not know about the readelf.

Answer (score 5):

When re-visiting this question 10 years later one must mention the little Python-based wrapper for readelf and nm that is [elf-size-analyze](https://github.com/jedrzejboczar/elf-size-analyze):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This tool works really great! I'm using it on PIC32 microcontroller `.elf` files to analyze RAM usage of various files and variables to find out where we can save memory.

Answer (score 2):

[`puncover`](https://github.com/HBehrens/puncover) uses `objdump` and a few other gcc tools to generate html pages you can easily browse to figure out where your code and data space is going.

It's a much nicer frontend than the text output of the gcc tools.