# Can an archive file store external links?

Tags: android, linux, webrtc

I am trying to link my Android app with a third-party archive. This archive, `libvpx_new.a,`is one among many archives that are being created as part of building webrtc for Android (on Ubuntu). I copy this archive and the header files into `C:\ThirdParty` directory on Windows. My Android app tries to link with `ThirdParty/libvpx_new/libvpx_new.a`.

When the build runs, I get link errors such as:

```
xxx/arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot open
C:/ThirdParty/libvpx_new/source/libvpx/vp8/libvpx_new.vp8_dx_iface.o:
No such file or directory
```

If I simply copy all the missing object files (in appropriate subdirectories), my build goes through. It is as if the archive file `libvpx_new.a` contains links to the object files instead of storing the actual functions.

Is this possible? If so, is there a way to fix the archive file to just absorb the object files instead of pointing to them? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out archives can indeed store external links. Such archives are called "thin" archives. Look at [Turn thin archive into normal one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554621/turn-thin-archive-into-normal-one) to convert thin archives to normal archives.