# show largest symbols in certain section (GNU gcc/binutils)

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, sections, binutils

In my embedded project, I need to figure out where I start to further optimize (i.e. reduce) stuff in the `.data` section. What command(s) do you use for an quick overview which symbols reserve large amounts of memory in a certain section? I use [the gcc-arm-embedded tools](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). Currently, I use the `-Xlinker -Map=file.map` flag to `gcc` at compile time, but searching for large address gaps that indicate large memory blocks in use is tedious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analyzing an ELF binary to minimize its size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513771/analyzing-an-elf-binary-to-minimize-its-size)

Comment: I don't want to know "What is being linked in that balloons the file size so much?". I know my ldscript pretty well because I wrote it. I want a list of symbols sorted by size in a specific section.

Comment: The last answer sounds like your problem, and from your response, you did not read it: `nm --print-size --size-sort`

Comment: That command does not exactly do what I intended (specific section[s]), but can be changed to `arm-none-eabi-nm file -rSC --size-sort |grep " [bBdDrR] "` for .bss, .data and .rodata or `arm-none-eabi-nm file -rSC --size-sort |grep " [dD] "`for the .data section only.

Comment: exactly.   Since the necessary information had been presented before, I suggested a duplicate.